# Pause and resume robocopy

Tags: command-line, sharepoint-2010, robocopy

Does anyone know how to pause and resume a robocopy task. I am moving a lot of files between servers and was hoping to do the move over two days but do not know whether it is possible to pause and then resume the task once reconnected to the network?

So ye the ask is does anyone know how, once your robocopy task has started, to pause and then resume it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sure, I was in the same situation... it´s magic.. just hit the "Pause" key @ the keyboard.. and see the task manager, the network output....

Enjoy...

Answer (score 3):

The [Pause] key does pause the copying of the files as mentioned. But I found that using the [Pause] key again did not continue the copy. However pressing [Enter/Return] key did resume the copying.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `Pause` key to pause and any key to resume, you can also use the mouse: `Left click` to pause, `Right click` to resume.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+S stops all output to the terminal which can be restarted with Ctrl+Q

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137842/what-is-the-point-of-ctrl-s